# sort out the values in the dropdown list

Tags: jquery

How can i sort the drop down list values

```
data.forEach(function (n) {
      html += '<option value="' + i + '">' + n.url + '</option>';
      i++;
alert(i)
    });
```

for example `n.url` displays in the dropdown as

```
value1
value2
value3
value4
```

How can i display the values in the following way

```
value4
value3
value2
value1
```

`data` contains 5 more values.I have to display the last value as first in the drop down list.How it is possible ?

Comment: sort your `data` first and loop it

Comment: Are you looking for `data.reverse().forEach(...)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's an array, you can try to reverse it first before looping using [reverse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse):

```
data = data.reverse()
```